# Empty push notification on install using Exacttarget:3.5.0 and android 5.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I've successfully configured ET 3.5.0 in my app and have been able to send push notifications to the device from the ETMC as well.

**Unfortunately, there's an empty push notification on my device each time  I install the app.** I haven't seen it on upgrade (so far), but it's really annoying to have an empty push show up even in release variants of the app.

How can I fix this?

please NOTE - I've experienced the same issue using ExactTarget v4.0.x as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty push notification is a result of a new message being sent from Google when your application is initially installed.  This is a known bug in versions 3.5.x of our SDK as well as versions 4.0.0 - 4.0.3, but was corrected in version 4.0.4.

Comment: AFAIK, I experienced the same issue with v4.0.4. Let me retry and check again, it's possible I'm mistaken. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: looks like v.4.0.4 fixed the problem after all, but it bought up a new issue - al the unit tests in the app fail with the same error message. Maybe I'll post a new question.

`**java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 231**'
    'Exception Details:
      Location:   com/exacttarget/etpushsdk/ETPushReceiver.onReceive(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V @28: new
      Reason:
        Expected stackmap frame at this location.`

Comment: follow-up question here - http://goo.gl/dWZcIw